# PHP Caching not working on Included File

Tags: php, web-services, caching, buffer

I have a web form that has an included file that outputs select options for states. The html looks like

```
    <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <?php include ("resources/data/stateoptions.php"); ?>
      </select>
```

The state options makes a call to a web service so that the list of store locations is always current. It seems however that this contact form page runs exceptionally slow (much faster if I remove this include). So I want to cache the web service call. My state options file looks like this

```
<?php
  $cachefile = "cache/states.html";
  $cachetime = 5 * 60; // 5 minutes

  // Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
  if (file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile))) 
  {
     include($cachefile);

     echo "<!-- Cached ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." 
     -->n";

     exit;
  }

  ob_start(); // start the output buffer
?>

<?php
//url of locations web service
$serviceURL = 'http://webserviceurl/state';

//query the webservice
$string = file_get_contents($serviceURL);

//decode the json response into an array
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

foreach( $json_a as $State => $IdealState){
$IdealState = $IdealState[State];
$IdealState2 = str_replace(' ', '-', $IdealState);
echo '<option value='.$IdealState2.'>'.$IdealState.'</option>';
}
?>

<?php
// open/create cache file and write data
$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w'); 
// save the contents of output buffer to the file
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); 
// close the file
fclose($fp); 
// Send the output to the browser
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

When I call this file directly, everything works as expected, and a states.html file is created. For some reason however when the stateoptions.php file is included in my contact form page, it never creates a cache file, and the speed problem persists. I'm a fairly novice programmer, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would comment out section at a time in the file to see which part is the problem.

Comment: Also I see that you do no sanitation of the remote data you fetch which goes into `states.html` as such you should not do `include($cachefile);` as malicious PHP code embedded in the JSON and then in `states.html` will run on the server. The file does not have to be .php for that to occur as `include()` does not care. Use `echo file_get_contents('states.html');` instead.

Comment: Well the data that come through is json from my own company, do you think I still need to?

Comment: I would as it would not change the outcome to the browser, PHP will not needlessly parse the file for code, and what if your company's JSON server got hacked? It would make sense to use the proper function regardless. =o)

Comment: You're right. I also wouldn't want leads to not come in if the server should go down for some reason and not output the json. How would I go about validating it?

Comment: @cryptic `echo file_get_contents()`? Really? I thought you knew better than that. `readfile()` woman!

Comment: @DaveRandom, I've always only used readfile() for sending files for download to browser, I suuuppoose it could be used here as well =oP

Comment: @cryptic I would say *never* `echo file_get_contents()` because it loads the whole file into memory before writing it to the ob. `readfile()` is a stream-to-stream copy, so it is a lot more efficient in general. Only do `file_get_contents()` if you need to manipulate the string in some way.

Comment: so you're saying make sure its saving it as html, and I can go with `<?php include ("resources/data/stateoptions.html"); ?>` and it shouldn't be able to run any malicious code since it's html not php right? Should I be using include, or read file? What is the difference?

Comment: @Evan Swap `include` for `readfile` in the above line and you should be safe and you should get the same result. `include` is not safe to use in this situation because it treats the file as PHP code - so if the file contained e.g. `<?php exec('rm -rf /'); ?>` somewhere in it then bad things could happen. But `readfile()` just outputs the file contents to the browser, so it would mitigate the problem. It would also be more efficient as PHP will not attempt to parse the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely going to be relative paths and working directories. The included file inherits its working directory from the calling script, it does **not** get a working directory of the location in which it resides automatically.

You either need to use the something like the magic `__DIR__` constant to construct an absolute path, or adjust the relative path accordingly.

I'm going to go out on a limb a little bit here and say that if you change the first line to:

```
$cachefile = "resources/data/cache/states.html";
```

...you will probably find it works at you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave that was it! unfortunately however, when it exits, it's not loading the rest of the page. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I got it by switching out exit for an else statement. Thanks!

Comment: @Evan Sorry I totally missed that follow-up question, glad you sorted it :-)